# Copying folders and creating names from user accounts Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, scripting, windows-10

I'm trying to make a script where i can copy outlook sig folders from all users on the machine into a new folder based on account name. So the folder will be like

c\temp\Nathan\sig
c\temp\James\sig

Here is what i have so far

```
Copy-Item c:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures -Recurse -destination c:\msp\$env:username
```

I'm assuming the star will go through each user but it doesn't work. Any care to share how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break this out into two steps.

1. Get all of the user Profiles
2. If there is a Microsoft\Signatures path there, move it to your destination.

This should get you going.

```
$profiles = Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Directory

foreach ($profile in $profiles){
    $signaturePath = "$($profile.FullName)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures"
    "checking $signaturePath for user signatures..."

    if (test-path $signaturePath){
        $newPath = "c:\msp\$($profile.BaseName)"
        "!!signature path found"
        Copy-Item -Path $signaturePath -Recurse -Destination $newPath
    }
    else{
        "--not found"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.